# Import without specifying index in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

How can I configure my react application so I do not need to specify index on my imports?

```
-src
|- app.jsx
|- views
 |- sample
  |- sample.css
  |- sample-container.jsx
  |- sample-view.jsx
  |- index.jsx
```

Currently I have to do this:

`import Sample from "src/views/sample/index"`

What I want to do is this:

`import Sample from "src/views/sample"`

I used `create-react-app` for initial set up and already ran `npm run eject`

Comment: It can be done in this way check code at codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ov1006yr19

Comment: I don't see anything there that helps...

Comment: You can check I am importing sample from directly folder instead of file

Check the sample folder. First I am importing in index file than I exported from index.js and then directly importing from folder instead of file

Comment: Is the issue that I'm using .jsx, or is it a setting you updated in package.json or what needs to be updated... You are giving me an example that is different from what I'm requesting help with

Comment: No I haven't updated any setting or Its not issue with jsx
Its just I am importing a file in index.js and exporting from there

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an issue with creating new `index.jsx` file while the server is started. Shutting down the server and starting it back up (`npm start`) seems to resolve the issue.